# Why aren't these nested modules' selectors recognized in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Angular 6.0.9
Angular-Cli 6.1.2

Picking up Angular and starting my first project.  I've got a nested module **dashboard-newsfeed.module.ts**, that I think I'm exporting back into the parent module **dashboard-module.ts** which is ultimately passed back into the main **app.module.ts**.

I'm getting an error in the following component html.

**dashboard-newsfeed.component.html**

```
<div class="component-wrapper">    
    <div class="content">
        <app-dashboard-newsfeed-content></app-dashboard-newsfeed-content>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <app-dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar></app-dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar>
    </div>
</div>
```

For whatever reason this is returning an error in javascript saying that it doesn't recognize the selectors **< app-dashboard-newsfeed-content >** or **< app-dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar >**.

This only started happening after I included **DashboardNewsfeedSidebarModule** in the following modules imports and exports.  I included this module in an effort to correct an earlier error where router-outlet wasn't being recognized by a module nested in **dashboard-newsfeed**.

Can someone explain why it isn't recognizing the selectors in **dashboard-newsfeed.component.html**?  How would I go about correcting it?

I've included the other files in case they might be relevant to solving the issue.  Any sort of help would be appreciated!

**dashboard-newsfeed.module.ts**

```
1   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  1 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
  2 import { DashboardNewsfeedContentComponent } from './dashboard-newsfeed-content/dashboard-newsfeed-content.component';
  3 import { DashboardNewsfeedSidebarComponent } from './dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar/dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar.component';
  4 
  5 import { DashboardNewsfeedSidebarModule } from './dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar/dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar.module';
  6 @NgModule({                
  7   imports: [               
  8       CommonModule,
          DashboardNewsfeedSidebarModule
  9   ],
      exports: [
           DashboardNewsfeedSidebarModule
      ],
 10     declarations: [
 11         DashboardNewsfeedContentComponent, 
 12         DashboardNewsfeedSidebarComponent
 13     ]
 14 })
 15 export class DashboardNewsfeedModule { }
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
1   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  1 import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router'; 
  2 import { DashboardComponent } from './/dashboard.component';
  3 import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
  4 
  5 import { DashboardHomeComponent } from './dashboard-home/dashboard-home.component';
  6 import { DashboardStoreComponent } from './dashboard-store/dashboard-store.component';
  7 import { DashboardNewsfeedComponent } from './dashboard-newsfeed/dashboard-newsfeed.component';
  8 import { DashboardAppointmentsComponent } from './dashboard-appointments/dashboard-appointments.component';
  9 import { DashboardNetworkComponent } from './dashboard-network/dashboard-network.component';
 10 import { DashboardScheduleComponent } from './dashboard-schedule/dashboard-schedule.component';
 11 import { DashboardOptionsComponent } from './dashboard-options/dashboard-options.component';
 12 import { DashboardEmployeesComponent } from './dashboard-employees/dashboard-employees.component';
 13   
 14 export const DashboardRoutes: Routes=[ 
 15     {path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
 16         children: [
 17             {path: '', component: DashboardHomeComponent},
 18             {path: 'newsfeed', component: DashboardNewsfeedComponent},
 19             {path: 'schedule', component: DashboardScheduleComponent},
 20             {path: 'settings', component: DashboardOptionsComponent},
 21             {path: 'employees', component: DashboardEmployeesComponent},
 22             {path: 'store', component: DashboardStoreComponent},
 23             {path: 'network', component: DashboardNetworkComponent}
 24         ]
 25     }
 26 ];
 27 
 28 @NgModule({                
 29     imports: [RouterModule.forChild(DashboardRoutes)],
 30     exports: [RouterModule]
 31 })
 32   
 33 export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
1 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  1 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
  2 import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './/dashboard-routing.module';
  3 import { DashboardNewsfeedModule } from './dashboard-newsfeed/dashboard-newsfeed.module';                                                                                                     
  4 
  5 import { DashboardScheduleComponent } from './dashboard-schedule/dashboard-schedule.component';
  6 import { DashboardOptionsComponent } from './dashboard-options/dashboard-options.component';
  7 import { DashboardEmployeesComponent } from './dashboard-employees/dashboard-employees.component';
  8 import { DashboardStoreComponent } from './dashboard-store/dashboard-store.component';
  9 import { DashboardNewsfeedComponent } from './dashboard-newsfeed/dashboard-newsfeed.component';
 10 import { DashboardNetworkComponent } from './dashboard-network/dashboard-network.component';
 11 import { DashboardHomeComponent } from './dashboard-home/dashboard-home.component';                                                                                                           
 12 
 13 import { DashboardComponent } from './/dashboard.component';
 14 import { DashboardHomeContentComponent } from './dashboard-home/dashboard-home-content/dashboard-home-content.component';
 15 import { DashboardStoreContentComponent } from './dashboard-store/dashboard-store-content/dashboard-store-content.component';
 16 import { DashboardHomeSidebarComponent } from './dashboard-home/dashboard-home-sidebar/dashboard-home-sidebar.component';
 17 import { DashboardStoreSidebarComponent } from './dashboard-store/dashboard-store-sidebar/dashboard-store-sidebar.component';                                                                 
 18   
 19   
 20 @NgModule({
 21   imports: [
 22       CommonModule,
 23       DashboardRoutingModule,
 24       DashboardNewsfeedModule,
 25   ],
 26   exports: [
 27       DashboardRoutingModule,
 28       DashboardNewsfeedModule,
 29   ],
 30     declarations: [        
 31         DashboardComponent,
 32 
 33         DashboardScheduleComponent,     
 34         DashboardOptionsComponent,      
 35         DashboardStoreComponent,        
 36         DashboardNewsfeedComponent,     
 37         DashboardNetworkComponent,      
 38         DashboardHomeComponent,
 39         DashboardEmployeesComponent,    
 40         DashboardHomeContentComponent,  
 41         DashboardHomeSidebarComponent,  
 42         DashboardStoreContentComponent, 
 43         DashboardStoreSidebarComponent,                                                                                                                                                       
 44     ],
 45     bootstrap:[DashboardComponent]
 46 })
 47 export class DashboardModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
1   import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
  1 import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router'; 
  2 
  3 export const routes: Routes=[
  4     {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}
  5 ];
  6 @NgModule({                
  7     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], 
  8     exports: [RouterModule]
  9 })
 10 
 11 export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
1   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  1 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  2 import { DashboardRoutingModule} from './dashboard/dashboard-routing.module';
  3 import { HomeComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar-dash/home/home.component';
  4 import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module'; 
  5   
  6 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  7   
  8 import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module'; 
  9 import { StoreComponent } from './store/store.component'; 
 10 import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
 11       
 12       
 13 @NgModule({
 14   declarations: [
 15     AppComponent,
 16     StoreComponent,
 17     ProfileComponent,
 18   ],
 19   imports: [
 20     BrowserModule,
 21     AppRoutingModule,
 22     DashboardModule,
 23   ],
 24   providers: [],
 25   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 26 })  
 27 export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You **`should not`** export any **`Modules`**, you should export only the components which are shared across other components.

Remove any modules under exports and add only the necessary components which you want to share across other module.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in your modules, only component need to be export not module

`dashboard-newsfeed.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardNewsfeedContentComponent } from './dashboard-newsfeed-content/dashboard-newsfeed-content.component';
import { DashboardNewsfeedSidebarComponent } from './dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar/dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar.component';
  import { DashboardNewsfeedSidebarModule } from './dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar/dashboard-newsfeed-sidebar.module';

const COMPONENTS = [
    DashboardNewsfeedContentComponent, 
    DashboardNewsfeedSidebarComponent   
];

   @NgModule({                
     imports: [               
        CommonModule,
        DashboardNewsfeedSidebarModule
     ],
      declarations: [
         ...COMPONENTS
      ],
      exports: [
        ...COMPONENTS
      ]
  })
  export class DashboardNewsfeedModule { }
```

and remove below code from `dashboard.module.ts`

```
exports: [
        DashboardRoutingModule,
        DashboardNewsfeedModule,
    ],
```